# Number of digits in increasing powers of $3$ till $99$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the number of digits in $$\sum_{n=0}^{99}3^n$$
This seems quite easy as$:$

Let
$$S=3^0+3^1+3^2+...+3^{99}$$ then $$3S=3^1+3^2+...+3^{100}$$ or $$2S=3^{100}-1$$ or $$S=\frac{3^{100}-1}{2}$$ Now number of digits in $3^{100}$ is $48$ and since $3^{100}$ is not in the form of $10^k$ so number of digits in $3^{100}-1$ is also $48$.

But at this moment I am facing a bit problem$-$ What will be the number of digits in $S$ where $S$ is a number obtained by dividing a $48$ digit number by $2$.

First of all if $S$ is not even will we count the decimal digits(though it is not asking for significant figures). And if $S$ is even then how to find number of digits of $S$(same problem if $S$ is odd). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit$-$ According to me the answer should either be $48$ or $47$

Comment: Questions about the number of digits of something are usually easy to solve using logarithms (the floor of the logarithm base 10 of the number is interesting). Give it a shot and write back if you still have problems with it

Comment: I have calculated the number of digits in $3^{100}-1$ using logarithms only but I could not found the number of digits when it is divided by $2$

Comment: Think about what happens when you divide by 2. If the leading digit is $2$ or more (for example, $300$ divided by $2$) you can just divide it by $2$ and carry on. However, when it is $1$ (as in $100$), the number of digits is $1$ less than it was. Either you remove one digit, or are left with the same number. If it is a test question, it shall not be that big of a problem

Comment: You can still deduce this with logarithms though, as $\log_{10}(\frac{a}{2}) = \log_{10}(a) - \log_{10}(2)$ by the rules of logarithms

Comment: yeah i got it thanks

Comment: Np, have a nice day

Comment: By the way, while it is irrelevant, note that $S$ must be even.  This is because if you examine the number $3^k$, you have that when $k$ is odd, then $3^k \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and when $k$ is even, then $3^k \equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, whether $S$ is even or not is not important at all. I'll use decimal logarithm to count digits.

$3^{99}<S<3^{100}$, so $47.2...=99\log_{10}<\log_{10}S<100\log_{10}3=47.7...$.

It means $3^{99}, 3^{100}$ are both 48-digit numbers, so $S$ is also 48 digit number.

Comment: I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let consider $\, 3^{10}=59049=60000\times(1-\underbrace{\frac{317}{20000}}_a)$

Now we would like to prove that $2\cdot 10^{47}<3^{100}<10^{48}$ so that the division by $2$ is not an issue.

$\begin{align}\ln(3^{100})
&=10\ln(3^{10})\\
&=10(\ln(60000)+\ln(1-a))\\
&=10(5\ln(2)+\ln(3)+4\ln(5)+\ln(1-a)\\
&=50\ln(2)+10\ln(3)+40\ln(5)+10\ln(1-a)\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\ln(10^{48})
&=48\ln(10)\\
&=48\ln(2)+48\ln(5)\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\ln(2\cdot 10^{47})
&=\ln(2)+47\ln(10)\\
&=48\ln(2)+47\ln(5)\end{align}$

Since $\ln$ is an increasing function, we can compare the logarithms and the numbers will be ordered the same.

$E_1=\ln(10^{48})-\ln(3^{100})=-2\ln(2)-10\ln(3)+8\ln(5)-10\ln(1-x)=\overbrace{\ln(\underbrace{\frac{5^8}{2^2\cdot 3^{10}}}_{>1})}^{>0}-\overbrace{10\ln(\underbrace{1-a}_{<1})}^{<0}>0$

$E_2=\ln(3^{100})-\ln(2\cdot 10^{47})=2\ln(2)+10\ln(3)-7\ln(5)+10\ln(1-a)={\ln(\underbrace{\frac{2^2\cdot 3^{10}}{5^7}}_{>1})+10\ln(1-a)}$

This time we cannot conclude so easily because the first term is positive and the second one negative, so we'll have to compare them more thoroughly.

We can use $$\ln(x)\ge 1-\frac 1x\quad\forall x>0$$

We get $\ E_2\ge 1-\dfrac{5^7}{2^2\cdot3^{10}}+10-\dfrac{10}{1-\frac{317}{20000}}=\dfrac{120031}{236196}>0$

> $$2\cdot 10^{47}<3^{100}<10^{48}\quad\text{therefore}\quad\dfrac{3^{100}-1}2\text{ has 48 digits}$$